# How do I change the source of an image if an error occurs?

Tags: angular

Why does the following statement throw an error?

**Idea:** To show an image from the normal URL. If it's not found (404), show a fallback image.

**Work Done:**

```
<img [src]='image_path + item.leafname' (error) ="[src] = 'fallback_path + item.leafname'" height="200px" class="card-img-top">
```

**Error thrown:**

```
Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 7 in [[src] = 'image_path + item.leafname'] in ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html@46:60
```

**Other Answers:**
I found alternative answers on Stack, which suggests using `ng-src` for the usual image and `onerror = "this.src='url'"` for a fallback image. But, how do I do the same using the [src] binding and (error) event binding?

Comment: It looks like this question is about Angular, so I have removed the angularjs tag. That tag is for questions about AngularJS 1.0.

Comment: You should implement this logic in the component, not in the template.

You can bind [src] to a variable that resolves to one or another in case of problems

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should implement this logic in the component, not in the template.

Then change your template like so:

```
<img [src]='image_path + item.leafname' (error) ="changeSource($event, item.leafname)">
```

Then create an error handler, like so:

```
changeSource(event, name) { event.target.src = this.fallback_path + name; }
```

Which updates the image source to your fallback source.

Comment: The `img` tag is inside a for loop. So, I'll not be able to bind `[src]` to a variable.

Comment: @Benedict Can you hold the src as an attribute against your array element? Or you could store the paths in a separate array, and use the for loop index to access it

Comment: I tried this. But, I couldn't figure why it isn't working. `<img [src]='image_path + item.leafname' (error) ="changeSource($event, item.leafname)"` Inside the component, `changeSource(event, name)
  {
    event.src = this.fallback_path + name;
  }`

Comment: Because `event` is not the element. You could try `event.target.src`?

Comment: Thanks! That listens and responds on an error, but the variable `name` is undefined in the handler, whereas `item.leafname` when used in the `[src]` binding works fine.

Comment: No issues, I found the error (it was something related to the variable names). Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
if(typeof(src)==="undefined")
{
$("#imageID").attr("src","yourNewSource_goes_here");
}
```

If that doesn't work, you can try this:

```
if(document.getElementById("myImg").complete==false)
{
$("#myImg").attr("src","another_source_goes_here");
}
```

Comment: Answer no longer relevant as the question uses Angular, not AngularJs which it was originally tagged with. It's also a partial answer.